# Monogame: AdMob-Ads only get visible after minimizing the app

Tags: android, xamarin, admob, monogame

I am currently trying to add AdMob-Ads to a Monogame-App. But they seem to never appear directly. Sometimes they appear after minimizing the app and maximizing it. So I am pretty sure that I am doing things like ad size, ad id etc. correctly.

Here's my code:

```
    public void CreateAds(Game1 window, Activity1 mainActivity)
    {
        _mainActivity = mainActivity;
        var frameLayout = new FrameLayout(_mainActivity);
        var linearLayout = new LinearLayout(_mainActivity);
        linearLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        linearLayout.SetGravity(Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center | Android.Views.GravityFlags.Bottom);
        frameLayout.AddView((View)window.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));

        adView = new AdView(_mainActivity);
        adView.AdUnitId = AD_UNIT_ID;
        adView.AdSize = AdSize.Banner;

        linearLayout.AddView(adView);
        frameLayout.AddView(linearLayout);
        _mainActivity.SetContentView(frameLayout);

        try
        {
            var adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.DeviceIdEmulator)
                .AddTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
                .Build();

            adView.LoadAd(adRequest);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This only happens for the first loaded ad. So my solution at the moment is to just load a second ad directly after and show that one.